# iOS "Open in background" animation recreated in CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, ios, css, animation, web-applications

Im looking at a way to recreate the iOS safari animation of when you open a link in the background (the item jumps up an quickly animates to a where you can get to it from) - This animation is also present on OSX Safari save to reading list.

Does anyone know how to recreate this animation/effect in CSS/JS for a web based app I'm working on OR seen a library/tut that helps with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to move the animated element out of the browser then you might be out of luck with just js/css. If the animation is contained within the browser window then you can use jQuery? http://jquery.com

There are plenty of animation apis in the library to do what you are saying - `clone -> move + zoomIn together -> move -> move + zoomOut together -> finally add to new location in DOM`. You can also control the animation speed and acceleration with easing functions.

Here is a fiddle i created where a rabbit goes into a bucket - http://jsfiddle.net/ydMAB/

In the fiddle above, the rabbit does not move in a curve. If you want that you can use the path plugin to jquery - https://github.com/weepy/jquery.path

**EDIT**: Added a fiddle example and changed jquery-ui to jquery since it suffices for the basic animations required in the context. Also added link to a path plugin to do a curved animation.